# PHP: alternate associative array notation not allowed inside class?

Tags: php, arrays, class

In PHP, this associative array notation works outside of a class:

```
$array['a'] = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$array['b'] = array('1', '2', '3', '4');
```

But inside a class, similar notation causes an error:

```
class Foo {
    protected $array['a'] = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
    protected $array['b'] = array('1', '2', '3', '4');
}

//Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';'
```

And yet this works just fine:

```
class Foo {
    protected $array = array('a'=>array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), 'b'=>array('1', '2', '3', '4'));
}
```

Any idea what's going on? The allowed notation can get really cumbersome with bigger arrays.

Comment: What's wrong with splitting the last definition into separate lines, one per sub-array?

Comment: Anyway, you're probably confusing class properties/fields with local variables. They are two entirely different things. You can't say `$array['a']` and `$array['b']` are distinct protected properties of instances of `Foo`, because they are actually offsets of a single array called `$array`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$array['a'] = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$array['b'] = array('1', '2', '3', '4');
```

this means the $array var was defined in the first line, in the second you only put stuff into it. 
That is why it won't work in a class, you cannot define the same variable twice.

Even more, the `[]=` is a modifying operator, which can not be used in class definition, the same reason you can not use the `++` sign. Not a deep programming or computer inability to do that, just a design decision not to do logic outside of methods inside a class (As opposed to JS or Ruby for example).

Of course, all that behaviour can be changed by "small" C hacking of the engine ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the technical reason why you can't do like you describe. Probably something silly and very low level. You could easily get around this, for a concrete class anyway, by setting the arrays in the constructor like this:

```
class foo {

protected $bar = new array();

  function __construct() {
    $array['a'] = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
    $array['b'] = array('1', '2', '3', '4');

    $this->bar = $array;
  }

}
```

Comment: The technical reason is simply that that's the wrong place to modify an existing variable. The right place is in, as you say, the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exact reason. Suppose php still has some kinks in its code.

```
class Foo {
    protected $array=array();
    public function Foo()
    {
    $array['b'] = array('1', '2', '3', '4');
    }
}
```

But this compiles ok. So you can just put the code in the constructor.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with

```
public function __construct() {
   $this->array['a'] = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
   $this->array['b'] = array('1', '2', '3', '4');
}
```

I can only postulate on the technical reasons for this.  A guess is that `[]` is an operation in php which can change the size in memory of a variable.  Class definitions should have a constant space in memory when initialized.